# Electric Scooter Battery charging issue

Tags: battery-charging, multimeter

I recently bought a second-hand electric scooter for the wife (for those interested it's a Rascal 588XL-S, around 10 years old).

The person I bought it off said the batteries were around 11 months old, and for the first couple of days everything was fine.

More recently after a few trips out it started cutting out going up hills, then on flat. I left it charging for a while and then noticed that the light on the charger was not lighting up and the cooling fan was not spinning.

I don't believe that it has actually charged since we got it, so I bought a multimeter and tested the two batteries. I get 11.8 and 11.3V respectively (they are 2 x 12V) - I don't know a lot about electronics but that leads me to believe that the batteries are in reasonable condition and have simply not been  charged since we brought it home. Does that sound like a reasonable assumption?

I can see no difference to voltage readings when testing with the charger plugged in - the only thing I've not checked properly is the charger itself, though I did take it to a scooter shop and they tried another working charger to no avail, so I'm thinking that somewhere there's a battery controller/circuit that I need to check.

How do I go about testing the charger itself - can I just put my multimeter on the charger pins (it's a 3 pin XLR connector) without blowing myself up/damaging something?

Comment: You'll need to test it under load. Also, change out that connector, using an XLR connector for power sounds like a *terrible* idea.

Comment: XLRs are, perhaps surprisingly, rated at 15A and not such a bad choice (unless you leave the charger in a recording studio!) But at 11.3V off load, that battery will sulphate and die unless you charge it ASAP.

Comment: Can I not test to see if it's even supplying current in the first place? How do I test under load? I assume I need to test the charging circuit whilst the charger is plugged in? Also, there are thousands of scooters that use an XLR connector to supply power - not sure why you would say it's a bad idea when hundreds of manufacturers are doing it.

Comment: @BrianDrummond the scary thing is I do have a small recording studio - my kids are old enough to know not to plug the charger into my mixer though.. though they have a habit of forgetting to drop the levels before they are switching instruments so we hear a lot of loud booms when instrument cables are swapped out!

Comment: Use of a 4 pin XLR for DC power is quite common, but 3 pin is a bad idea.

Comment: Get an XLR socket rather than poking bare pins with DMM leads. Look for about 14V from a lead-acid charger off load (13.8V is a typical float V, or 14.x for faster charge) decaying to about the battery V when charging.

Comment: @Finbarr again, I don't manufacture the chargers or make the choice of how many pins are in them/how many are used for charging - there are thousands of chargers with a 3pin XLR connector. 

Why is this an issue for people? Can we stop commenting about the XLR connector, it's beyond my control and can't be such a bad idea given than there are thousands of them out there.

Comment: @Finbarr, I thought 4 pin XLRs used smaller pins, which would be rated for lower current.  I've seen Speakons suggested as an alternative and they look good (higher current too!)

Comment: @BrianDrummond Yes, 4 way XLRs are rated at 10A